# update list array from child component

Tags: reactjs

new react user here.

i am trying to access form data in my parent app from the child form.  I am trying to alert or console the data from the parent so I can visually see what was typed in the form.  Once I can access the data in the parent I will try and move it to my list array.

PARENT

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    lists: [], 
    items: {} 
    };
}

handleAddList(s) {
     alert('I am calling function from child')

     console.log(this.refs.id.value) // this errors out on me
}

 render() {
 return (
    <div className="App">
    <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
    <div id="listsDiv" className="List">
    <Lists lists={this.state.lists} items={this.state.items} addItem {this.handleAddItem.bind(this)} />
    </div>
    </div>
 );
 }

 }
```

CHILD

```
class AddList extends Component {


handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   alert(this.refs.id.value)

   this.props.addList()

}

render() {
  return (
    <div id="addListDiv">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
    <div id='addList'>
    <label>What will be on your next list?&nbsp;
    <input type='text' ref='id' id='newID'></input>
    </label>
    </div><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Create List' />
    </form>
    </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHILD

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class AddList extends Component {


handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var day = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.id).value.trim();

  this.props.addList(day);

}

render() {
   return (
     <div id="addListDiv">
     <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
     <div id='addList'>
     <label>What will be on your next list?&nbsp;
     <input type='text' ref='id' id='newID'></input>
     </label>
     </div><br />
     <input type='submit' value='Create List' />
     </form>
   </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PARENT

```
class App extends Component {

handleAddList(args) {
   console.log(args);
}

render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddList addList={this.handleAddList.bind(this)} />
   </div>
   );
  }
 }
```

Edit it a little to work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the ref on the input using a callback, like this:

```
<input type='text' ref={input => { this.input = input; }} id='newID'></input>
```

Then access it in your event handler like this:

```
alert(this.input.value);
```

However, if you are new to React, you should try using controlled components before you try to use refs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html